# Dynamically Setting N in findByTopN in Spring JPA Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot application which has a Repository like this.

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {
  List<Employee> findTop3ByOrderBySalaryDesc();
}
```

Function `findTop3ByOrderBySalaryDesc` in above, finds the top 3 employees with the highest salaries. Is there a way to dynamically specify the number of employees in this example? For example, is it possible to kind of assign an integer parameter for this function which would determine the number of employees?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a Pageable object as parameter instead of "Top" keyword.
e.g.

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {
    List<Employee> findAllByOrderBySalaryDesc(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Then you need invoke the method, requesting a first page with a maximum of N elements.
e.g. to find a first page of first 100 elements:

```
List<Employee> list = repo.findAllByOrderBySalaryDesc(PageRequest.of(0, 100));
```

Also you can use a "findAll" method and specify a custom order during invocation:
e.g.

```
List<Employee> list = repo.findAll(PageRequest.of(0, 100, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "salary")));
```

Take a look to this tutorials:

[limiting query results](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-limit-query-results)

[spring data jpa pagination and sorting](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting)